# How to avoid boats on a mainly oceanic world?

Tags: science-based, technology, physics, geography, weather

On an Earth-like planet with clustered continents and large oceans, like Pangaea, the easiest method of travel would be boats. However, I am looking to avoid humans using boats. I define a boat as some kind of fast transportation over water. This includes taming animals or any other water-based method of transportation. The society in question is similar to Ancient Greece in terms of the technological age and expansion. I am also looking for a hard-science answer.

**My limitations are:**

- No cultural norms or governmental decrees (these tend to be
  misinterpreted or changed over time)
- The oceans must remain similar to Earth, being mostly water with some
  minerals.
- The continents must be clustered together
- The humans must be human (no morphological changes).
- The planet must stay in the tropical to temperate temperature range.
- Whatever strategy is devised must be long-term, like how boats have been around for about 10,000 years.

**What can be changed:**

- The weather
- Any geographic features on the continent
- Technological limitations
- Really anything as long as the planet stays Earth-like and habitable.

**Clarifications:**

- Riverboats and small inland transportation are ok, I just don't want seaworthy ships.
- Extreme weather, like strong winds on the ocean, is preferable but there needs to be a way for humans to live normally without any extra gear, like goggles for wind.

Comment: *Five Hundred Thousand Years?* 99.99% of all human technology was invented in the last 150 years. And you want something that will remain for 500,000 years? What angry god is restricting your population's natural curiosity and inclination to solve problems? I know this isn't really intrinsic to your question ... but are you sure? That's so unrealistic it might cause cancer. 

Comment: The [tag:hard-science] tag may be too limiting for this question, as I expect it will be difficult to cite papers/etc that would apply to your scenario. Perhaps [tag:science-based] would be better.

Comment: The entire history of human civilization spans less than 7,000 years. There weren't even any anatomically modern humans 500,000 years ago... Moreover, asking about a society *"similar to Ancient Greece"* except without ships is like asking about a society similar to the USA, except landlocked, surrounded by powerful enemies and ruled by a hereditary theocracy: the *essence* of Ancient Greece was seaborne trade. Romanian ditty: *"Furthermode, the story seeks to expand upon the Greeks; and it's obvious to see that the Greeks trade on the sea".*

Comment: Human technology using more than knapped stones and bones (e.g. Brick) is only about 5-6000 years old!

Comment: Lots of nations inhabited lands with access to the sea. Some of those nations (the Greeks, the English, the French, the Dutch etc.) went to sea, and developed large efficient trade networks. Other nations, although they had ample access to the sea, did not. The Persians, the Indians, the Japanese developed sophisticated civilizations, but, although they had easy access to the sea, never ventured far from home and never used the sea as a way of communication. In the Classical World, there was a lot of trade between India and Europe: and all of it was carried in Greek ships, not in Indian ships.

Comment: @AlexP the Japanese developed **ample** sea tradition as fishermen, and till the 1600s had some rather large navies! It was the invasion of Korea that ended with them lacking in a navy for 250 years.

Comment: @Trish: Well, *everybody* had some fishing boats and did a little trade. The point is that they never ventured far; Japan to Korea is only about 100 miles. (I don't know of any example of absolute avoidance of the sea: that's why I just posted a comment instead of answering the question.)

Comment: @AlexP 240 miles from Tanegashima to Okinawa island, the central of the Kingdom of Okinawa, who's king was subordinate of the Setsuma. 300 from Kagoshima.

Comment: what about raft? and what transportation they use to travel sea then? i think that would help to eradicate the use of boat, if they have preferable/superior transportation in the first place.

Comment: Would you be happy with no *ocean-worthy* ships? A thought I got that may be your planet lacks a magnetic field making navigation too difficult when out of sight of land. There are substitutes to compasses, but.. Hmm. Not sure that's good enough :-(

Comment: Why on earth would anyone wish to avoid boats? Does not compute.... and Ratty agrees.  "There is nothing in life, half so much worth doing, as simply ... messing about in boats"

Comment: Also, if you have pangea, why do you need a boat? everything is within walking distance...

Comment: Boats are older than Homo sapiens. Homo erectus was a sailor. https://www.theguardian.com/science/2018/feb/20/homo-erectus-may-have-been-a-sailor-and-able-to-speak

Comment: "On an Earth-like planet with clustered continents and large oceans, like Pangaea, the easiest method of travel would be boats."  Why use **ships** when there's one giant continent?

Comment: @RonJohn, even in the interior of North America, boats were an important mode of travel. Many (most?) important settlements were along rivers. It’s a lot easier to float loads of goods, than it is to drag or carry. Wagons are great, but you need roads. Rivers already *are* the roads. :)

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I specifically mentioned **ships**, because you typically **don't use boats** to sail out into "blue water".

Comment: @RonJohn, ya, apologies for the confusion. The OP that you quote talks about “boats”, and I misunderstood that you were just being loose with your terminology. FWIW, there are cases of Inuit reaching the British Isles in kayaks, likely the source of the selkie myth. One such account: http://www.orkneyjar.com/folklore/selkiefolk/origins/origin5.htm And there are the folks who have crossed oceans in rowboats. Bigger ships make ocean travel easier, but smaller boats can still do it.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi there are so many exceptions to "boats don't purposefully go out into blue water" that it took some time for me to decide on "you **typically** don't use boats" to sail out into blue water.  Because... **you don't**.  Those Inuit around Scotland were **RARE**, and crossing the ocean in a rowboat is even rarer and more of a stunt.  Definitely these are cases of the exceptions proving the rule.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Just make it so wood does not last on seawater

Your planet has a variant of the [Shipworm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shipworms), similar to the Earth variety except that it contains its own cellulose-dissolving enzyme rather than relying on bacterial assistance to do this job.

This would result in any unprotected wood in the seawater being leaky within a day, and riddled like a sieve within a week, like this one (which took about 2 months, here on Earth)
[image]

While it should be possible to build metal cladding or all-metal boats to protect against this, your people would have no reason to make this discovery, as they never encounter the need for it. All wooden constructions that touch seawater fail so rapidly, that they never develop an infrastructure that uses the sea. At all.

Is this hard-sciency enough for you? One very plausible change in one organism is all that is needed.

Comment: The fact that wood ships won't work would precisely be the reason for discovering metal cladding instead of trying to use not working wooden ship. Or more low tech animal skins spanned over a wood frame that is thus protected from the water.

Comment: "they never encounter the need for it" - we've explored the sky, space and the deep ocean, despite not having any *need* for that. If there's a way, someone will figure it out eventually, because that's what people do. Although it may be a believable enough explanation for fiction.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Bad analogy. Rather mention not developing a 5-lever doorlock, for a civilization that *does not use doors*

Comment: Likely this would lead to earlier adoption of tarring hulls to preserve the wood. Once the utility of early rafts and dugouts is observed, there would be pressure to keep using disposable craft (you don't need it to last years if you can quickly make a replacement after your week's journey) and protect the wood or larger and more expensive craft.

Comment: @PcMan Not sure why you say it's a bad analogy. Understanding how to protect against this would be a blocker to oceanic travel in the same way understanding aerodynamics was a blocker to flight (and there were similar blockers for space and underwater travel). Or, to use your phrasing: developing an engine / technique for flight, for a civilization that does not use flight, because that's exactly the thing that's needed to enable flight (and you mentioning they can only travel relatively short durations in water actually fits the analogy rather well, as that's exactly how flight started too).

Comment: I think that this is a good solution. While metal ships would fix this issue, it is a lot harder developing the concept of boats with metal. (Especially because metal sinks unless in a specific shape.) Realistically, I think that people would come up with a solution (worm repellants, leather covering, etc.), but I think this is the most realistic answer.

Comment: Wood is not necessary for boats.  At the low-tech end, there are things like the kayak and coracle that can be built from skin and bone. At a higher level, the US used concrete ships in both world wars, and there are ongoing concrete canoe competitions among the civil engineering departments of North American universities (and perhaps elsewhere?): https://www.asce.org/event/2021/concrete-canoe/  And of course these days you have fiberglass and other composites.

Comment: As James says, you'll need a 2nd reason why hide boats won't work well.

Comment: Mostly, because hide boats really, really suck on oceans. They are fine in canoe size, but do you feel like building an ocean-crossing vessel out of hide? Or even a large coast-hugger? Its not impossible, but it will severely discourage initial exploratory attempts.

Comment: Metal ships wouldn't work because A society of the level of ancient Greece would not have access to enough metal to build ships with it. At least if the geology of their planet is similar to that on Earth regarding how much metal ore is extractable for a pre-industrial society.

Comment: @PcMan: The question says that there's a Pangaea-like continent, so there wouldn't be a reason for long, ocean-crossing voyages, just coastwise and inter-island travel.  Coastwise, you wouldn't do it for exploration (which you could do by land), so much as for tradel  As for what can reasonably be done, look at what the Inuit do in kayaks.  That's even leaving out probably mythical things like the voyage of Brendan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan

Comment: @PcMan The Polynesians crossed oceans in canoes, several times.

Comment: @PcMan "They are fine in canoe size, but do you feel like building an ocean-crossing vessel out of hide?"  It's Pangea... There is no going over the ocean because **there's nowhere to go!!**  At best, they'll hug the shorelines, sailing from port to port down the coast.

Comment: @jamesqf A shipworm capable of eating hide as well as wood is not that far-fetched. Or two different species. But I agree with RonJohn that in a Pangea-like world the most probable reason there aren't ocean-worthy boats is because there's nowhere else to go. Small coastal boats is all they'll ever need.

Comment: @Rekesoft if they can eat leather that fast then their are no fish or marine mammals in your ocean, becasue the worms have eaten them.

Comment: @John Or, more probably, aquatic creatures have other mecanisms of defence: scales, poisonous skin, never stop swimming (worms aren't fast chasers), etc... Terrestrial animals don't have those because they don't need it. You could use whale hides to make your boats, then, but it is a chicken-and-egg problem: how do you make a boat to fish whales so you can make boats out of whale hide?

Comment: @Rekesoft Whales wash up on beaches, but if the worms are that easy to defeat then there will be natural woods that defeat them as well. there are naturally toxic woods.

Answer (score 31):

A second answer: **enormous tides.**

Your planet has a large moon like Earth does, but it's a lot closer, or in an elliptical orbit (perhaps as a result of a planetary collision a few millions of years ago), or perhaps your planet *is* a moon of a much larger gas giant and has not yet become tidally locked to it.

Either way, the tidal forces affecting your planet are a lot greater than those on Earth, and the result is that every day the tide comes rushing in in a giant wave, across many miles of land, all around the coast. This results in extreme coastal erosion that has created huge beaches all around the continent. Anything you try to build there will just get washed away the next time the tide comes in - there just isn't any way that you could build a functioning dock from which to launch a ship. You could launch a ship at high tide, but even if you make it to the open ocean before the tide goes out, there's no practical way for you to land again because there's no way you can navigate the white waters of the incoming tide. You could deliberately beach the ship, but then you won't get to use it more than once.

The extreme tidal forces would also make the planet a lot more tectonically active than the Earth, with a lot more volcanoes etc. Perhaps you could use this to explain why there is still a continent despite the extreme tidal erosion.

Comment: Good idea, but are fast&high tides really a problem for ships? Just anchor, beach and disembark/embark on low tide and set sail on high tide.

Comment: @Michael fair enough, it's possible that could work. But I'm imagining the tides being so strong that they'd be likely to destroy the ship if you tried to do that. Plus to get anything to or from the boat you'd have to transport it several miles down the beach, which is potentially quite difficult terrain (rocks, shelving, tidal pools, quicksand, ...), and unpredictable since the tides will change it every day. I'm imagining these issues would make it too dangerous or impractical to use ships for trade or fishing, especially since they'd have to be really quite sturdy before they'd work at all

Comment: I don’t know how anything about ships or how big you could make the tides before they have other side effects (like your planet breaking apart) but I’d think that something like 20m high tides every 12h would be quite manageable. One could even build a dock on wooden stilts for that height.

Comment: @Michael 20m is nothing even compared to what the Earth has experienced in the past, when the moon was closer. Hundreds of metres ought to be plausible. I'm talking about something resembling a major tsunami every day, which would just wash away any wooden jetty. The main limit on tide height is that if the tidal forces are too strong the crust can melt and you get a magma ocean instead of a land surface. (That has also happened on Earth in the past.) If this was [tag:hard-science] I'd see if there was a way to put numbers on that, but for [tag:science-based] I think it's ok to handwave it.

Comment: Note for all - I was very shocked to find that our once close moon, with enormous tides, quickly moved away to much lower tides in one hundred years.  That is a blink on a geological timescale.  Very surprising (and dashed many of my theories on early evolution!).  I had imagined millions of years of tsunamis but that is not the case.  I do not know if the slowdown is mostly due to the change in spin or the effect of massive oceans slowing it through tides

Comment: @MichaelDurrant thanks, that's useful information, and it makes sense - the energy for those huge tides has to come from somewhere, and that somewhere is the gravitational potential energy between the Moon and the Earth - which gets dissipated by the moon moving further away. So to make this realistic the planet probably would have to be a moon of a gas giant. (Io experiences much higher tidal forces than Earth - though it also has too much volcanism to be habitable, so the forces would need to be less than that.)

Comment: Overall I really like this answer, but there's something that undermines its validity: rivers. Rivers necessarily end up in the oceans, and the situation described in the answer doesn't prevent building littoral infrastructure on lakes and rivers. From there on out, there's a technological evolutionary path towards building ships that can survive in tidal basis, and eventually ships that can sail into the ocean. You could perhaps improve the answer with ways that prevent navigable rivers.

Comment: The height of tides is extremely influenced by geography. Ex Earth has a 0.6m tidal difference on the open ocean but 12-15m in the Bay of Fundy and almost 0 in the Mediterranean

Comment: Any protected sea or large lake would let the people practice ship building and sailing, and once they manage to get any large craft on the ocean they can just leave it there and use tiny, portable boats to (dis)embark.

Comment: I was about to post an answer about tides but it could actually just be a complement to your answer: Same setup you describe (difficult to build/embark/land), but they have little need to overcome that because the low tide provide land bridges (lasting long enough to make the trip oviously).

Comment: @user3067860 right, I was thinking of mentioning that. I think probably the tides would be much more dramatic if the seas are generally shallow near the continent (think breakers on a beach) and they might also be bigger on a mostly-ocean world since, unlike on Earth, they could move around the planet as a continuous wave without being dissipated, rather than sloshing back and forth from one continent to another. Resonance effects could amplify things also, like the Bay of Fundy but on a global scale. But these things are complicated and hard to predict, and I'm not very sure about them.

Answer (score 23):

Boats started off as simple tree trunks floating on the water, which where then carved to better accommodate the passengers.

But that can only happen if the wood is lighter than water. There are various types of [woods which are denser than water](https://www.wood-database.com/wood-articles/top-ten-heaviest-woods/), meaning that any trunk falling in the water would sink rather than floating.

Moreover some of those woods is also extremely difficult to work, such as the ironwood.

So, if your world has only that type of wood or similar, you are basically left with a much more difficult discover of the principles of floating on water. Not much more different than what has happened in our timeline with flying, which is something we have mastered in the very recent past of our millennial history.

Comment: Boats and rafts are very different things. A raft is not a boat, and a boat is definitely not a raft. Boats do not float because wood is ligher than water, they float because of the air they enclose. We have found [monoxyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dugout_canoe) boats 10,000 years old...

Comment: @AlexP Yes, but would you think to try to build a dugout if you had never seen wood float before?

Comment: Flying requires sufficient power vs mass and is a difficult problem. Floating is trivial - we float already. Any ordinary person that washes wooden cups in the river/sea/... would soon notice these cups float even though the wood itself sinks. Preventing discovery for an ancient Greece tech level seems impossible.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley: Would you think to build a telegraph if you had never seen wires carry words before? Some inventors are just crazy creative! Besides, all you have to do to "see" metal boat technology is to accidentally drop an empty metal pot into a sink full of dishwater. Any civilization that invents cooking and washing-up is basically one rich aristocrat away from inventing a giant metal pot-boat.

Comment: @Quuxplusone When you are working in the context of a civilization that already has a long history of transmitting messages by a variety of signaling methods (writing, semaphore, smoke signals, drums, battlefield pipes / trumpets / etc., bell pulls--which are literally actuated by signal-carrying wires!), and you have just discovered a new signaling method... then yes. Cf. never having seen any large inanimate object float.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to discourage the development and use of seagoing vessels may be to discourage associating with the sea itself: prolific [littoral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littoral_zone) and [neritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neritic_zone) predator species too large, dangerous, and/or difficult to hunt even in groups could, from an early stage, dissuade your people from going anywhere near ocean coasts and instead focus development on rivers and other freshwater bodies.

Comment: Relative to your account bio: "... and a chasing after the wind."

Comment: @Mandelbrot, just so you know, a good rule of thumb here is to wait 24 hours before accepting an answers. Not everyone is in your time-zone, so you can have great answer if you wait enough time (for example, both PcMan and Nathaniel answered after you accepted rek's answer).

Comment: Wanted to answer exactly this. Until the Humans have conquered modern firearms and metalworking to make armored ships they simply will not dare to go out to the sea.

Answer (score 12):

Here is another way, which could be combined with other answers: **make the planet cold**, either permanently or because it's in the middle of an ice age.

The idea is that only the equatorial region is really suitable for human habitation. If you go too far north or south everything is covered in glaciers and the sea is frozen. Seen from space, the planet is more than half covered by white ice caps, with a blue-green band around the equator, something very roughly like this:

[image]

The Earth has probably been in this kind of state several times in the past.

Now since the continents are all clustered together, there isn't much point in using boats. The human-habitable region is a letter-box shaped piece of land that runs across a single large continent in the east-west direction. The climate there is temperate, but to the north and south it's bounded by icy wastes rather than ocean. It has coastlines to the east and west, but they're relatively short, and to get from one to the other you'd have to sail around the entire planet.

This would severely limit the usefulness of ocean-going vessels. If you had them you could use them to travel north-south along the coastlines, but this would provide a lot less economic benefit than it does on our world, so there would be a lot less economic pressure to develop them in the first place. If the coastlines are not rocky then your people might just build railways or canals along the coasts instead, and then never really feel the need to develop shipping beyond sport and fishing. (The latter of course only applies if there are edible fish.)

Answer (score 9):

Your citizens suffer from terrible sea sickness, they don't just throw up, they get unconscious and maybe suffer long term damage.

So peaceful rivers would be fine, but even estuaries would be too choppy for your would-be sailors.

Actually this would be so anchored in collective knowledge that no-one would ever even try to go to sea. So you could have a sub-plot of some outlier who finds that it is possible after all, and acts accordingly...

Comment: As someone who gets motion sickness easily, this would put me right off.  The only ferry boat I can travel on *comfortably* is a catamaran, which powers through the waves with thumps and vibration, not wallowing back-and-forth.

Answer (score 7):

**Historical precedence**

The ancient Greeks didn't do any trans-oceanic travel anyway, so the question is arguably moot.

Before the armada days... there essentially was no ocean travel. Yes, brave Norse settlers made it to the Americas, but the travel was lengthy, arduous and risky enough that only a few made it to Greenland and a little beyond, and even they arguably got lucky: if North America had been a little more southerly, all they'd have found would've been sea ice.

[image: Greek trade routes, via Ancient History Encyclopaedia]
[Greek trade routes, via Ancient History Encyclopaedia]

So really, you don't even need to make any changes, apart from wiping out those pesky Norse adventurers, and making it so that the continents didn't have any convenient paths between them, like "hey if you just follow the edge of the sea ice west from Norway, you get to a McDonald's!".

However... that's not very "hard science" of me. In fact, science ([Feasible Ocean Routes to and from the Americas in Pre-Columbian Times](https://www.jstor.org/stable/278557?seq=1), quoting C[hronica-Botanica-Vol-xiv](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.7329/2015.7329.Chronica-Botanica-Vol-xiv-1950_djvu.txt)) says:

> It would be foolish to assert that there were no communications across the Pacific in pre-Magellan times

I feel that there is a fairly solid case for this being at least a thing that was feasible to happen at that time, given that [hundreds of plant species](http://www.sino-platonic.org/complete/spp133_precolumbian_voyages.pdf) have been found which appear to have spread between the continents with no other explanation.

We want ten thousand years of no seafaring, so we need defense in depth! Many layers! Travel between continents only when sea levels change and expose land bridges!

So while it might be a helpful factor, merely saying "OK, there are no easy paths, and no brave adventurers" won't cut it :)

**Predators**

Making seawater scary with predators, as rek suggests... again, it might be a useful additional tactic, but I don't think it would work, not for thousands of years for humans, anyway.

Waterfront property has been prime property as long as humans have existed. We migrated along waterways.

We take "dangerous" as a challenge. We've obliterated almost all large animals that we don't deliberately breed to eat, and all existing species are getting smaller as we kill and eat the biggest ones. For millennia we have harvested food from waters filled with shark and piranha and crocs and gators and vipers and poisoned sea urchins and deadly jellyfish and... and we eat them.

This isn't a new habit: we probably killed off the [NA mammoth and smilodon](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-07897-1.pdf?origin=ppub), and [likely were a contributing force](https://academic.oup.com/bioscience/article/60/7/516/234159) for much of the rest of the wave of Late Pleistocene Megafaunal Extinctions.

So, sure, have predators, but just as *one of many* reasons the sentient land-dwellers ("They") have, to avoid screwing with the ocean.

The most valuable kind of predator could be the ship-attacking kind. If any large craft going past the continental shelf runs a very good chance of getting capsized boned by aggressive or amorous whales, then most craft won't go past that line, at least until they realize how much ambergris, whalebone and whalemeat are *worth*.

Hrm, OK, we don't want to give them an economic incentive to venture out: maybe kraken, rather than whales, then.

**Nutrition vs Poison**

(I see @Kari beat me to this one, darn! Updoot for Kari!)

On Earth, we may well have taken to the water due to an aquatic phase in our evolution... but whether or not that is the case, we *stuck by* the water because it's a fantastic source of nutrition, such as DHA, an omega-3 found abundantly in human brains and in aquatic foods. This aquatic aspect of our diet may well have contributed to our large brains. Oh, and salt, we use a LOT of that, with our abnormal behaviors like sweating and crying.

If everything in the ocean was toxic to Them, They'd have no real interest. Add some heavy metals, radioactives, some lead and arsenic and some faster-acting things, to the seaweeds and shellfish, and have the toxins concentrate more and more up the entire food chain.

Perhaps make rock salt toxic to Them. That's extremely believable, given how toxic it is anyway. Or have other soluble minerals leech out of the rocks of the land and into the oceans.

But you don't even need to specify what toxins affect Them; just that sea animals have the ability to process ocean foods that They as land animals have since lost. Remove the omega-3s, or remove Their need or ability to process them.

**Provisions**

With no seals, polar bears, edible fish, etc to catch and eat, and nowhere to stop and find freshwater or meltable snow, travelers would be constrained by supplies they could take with them. With a large enough distance between, this would be a hindrance, and set a hard date for having to turn around, equal to less than half the provisions a craft could carry.

**Non-swimming**

We can swim and float, so can spend time in water, make dugout canoes that can tip us in without dying, and so on. Let's get rid of all that. Their species sinks in water. Heavy bones, dense muscles, small lungs, non-closing airways, no diving reflex, poorly formed for swimming... so not real fond of swimming in the first place, even less fond of swimming anywhere near the deep, toxic ocean.

**Conceptual leaps**

As L. Dutch pointed out, if the only buoyant stuff They ever see is bloated corpses, They'd take a while to even come up with the idea of floating airbags for travel, and those just aren't very ocean-worthy, but do well enough on rivers if you stick them under some kinda raft framework. Waterway dirigibles, pulled by draft animals trudging along the waterside, as we did with canals; or by pulling on a rope alongside the waterway.

It's admittedly a "small leap" from there to surrounding them in a solid sealed box instead of a mere framework, and from there to the discovery that it doesn't matter if the solid box has airbag in, or even whether it has holes in, so long as they're above the waterline, and from there to realizing that you can just float an open-topped box in a way that it won't flip over and drown everyone, and from there to ballast and sails and masts and rudders and rigging and then reinventing rigging to sail into the wind...

But even so... look how long it took us to develop wheeled vehicles (5500ya)! And another three thousand years after that (2400ya) to put teeth on it and make a cog, a thousand years after that (1300ya) to make a clock, and six hundred years more (700ya) to make a worm gear! Each of these, looking back, is a "small leap". And none of them kills us much if we screw it up. And even then, the wheel didn't really penetrate into sub-Saharan Africa until the Europeans turned up in the 1800s.

**Prevailing winds**

Hot air on land goes up. This means wind blows from the sea: a "[sea breeze](https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/educate/seabreeze_ans.shtml)". In the night, it blows the other way, as the land cools, but the sea stays warm. So Their more sensible sailors make sure to be home before that happens, rather than get stranded away from shore.

Why would they be stranded? Because with poor rigging tech, They couldn't tack into the wind very well.

If you also have a climate without any constant trade winds for their navigators to follow, the inconsistent and mercurial climate would mean that there'd be no obvious paths for people to try exploring in. I'm not sure how realistic a world without tradewinds and currents would be, though...

**Construction materials**

The Armadas of Britain, [Spain](https://academic.oup.com/envhis/article-abstract/17/1/116/423962), France, and Holland, were all formed from forestry. The devastating impact of the formation of the British armada on the countryside of the UK can hardly be overstated. Maintaining the armada required the formation of a proper forestry commission with control over sizeable tracts of land doing nothing but the slow process of growing trees long enough to lay straight keels, masts, and so on.

> I have heard that in the great expedition of 1588 it was expressly
> enjoined the Spanish commanders of that signal Armada that if, when
> landed, they should not subdue our nation, and make good their
> conquest, they should yet be sure not to leave a tree standing in the
> Forest of Dean.
> -- https://www.jstor.org/stable/550221?seq=1

If your civilization lacks wood as a construction material, and instead uses mostly stone, leather and metal, then that both sets a cool aesthetic, and helps to explain why large ships might not get built for some time: only perhaps coracles, for shallow freshwater marshes.

Answer (score 5):

**No non-perishable food which contains Vitamin C.**

This will only prevent long travel over open ocean.

Scurvy was a huge problem for Earth’s sailors and only really solved with lemons, limes and Sauerkraut. Just get rid of those foods and you should be fine.

Comment: Except that humans invented ships and used them long before we knew about it, and even long _after_ we knew about it.

Comment: Yes but it did create huge problems for ocean crossings. If average travel time had been slightly longer (more than ~3 months) I imagine it would have prevented it completely. Interestingly effective cures (e.g. lemons or pine needles) popped up throughout history several times but then were forgotten again.

Comment: @Michael yeah, but OP sounds like he's not just talking about 3 month plus travel, but also blocking people from Madagaskar and similar (or island hopping in southeast asia. Because these two things are perfectly feasible, if you REALLY want it probably without food even if you get a bit lucky

Answer (score 3):

### Here Be Dragons

For one reason or another (maybe not having an ice age), the sea life is... large. Very large. Whales are the size of large boats and armored. Their predators (think Mosasaurus from Jurassic World) have beaks capable of crushing that armor. They roam all coastal seas and boats get bitten in half before the Mosasaurus discovers there are only tiny snacks inside.

So humans use boats on rivers all the time, but get anywhere near the sea and it's just too dangerous. Every generation some foolhardy adventurers take a boat out to open sea and get themselves killed in front of the townsfolk just to remind the rest that it's still a really bad idea.

The aquatic predators can be of any type you like of course, but since they're still in the middle of an evolutionary arms race with the other huge sea life, they should be huge and mostly immune to anything humans can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no sea fishery, because all oceans are infested with poisonous jellyfish or something, that would keep people away from the sea.

Answer (score 1):

As you can change geography, you could make the sea full or sharp and point rocks, and add that is possible to change the weather, make it in a way that the cluster of the continents made significant changes in the atmosphere, as the Bermuda triangle, which resulted in strong storms at deep sea, making the previous detail even more dangerous.

But going a bit further, if you agree, its possible to make the geography of deep sea being composed of mainly volcanic like structures, which could heat up the water at dangerous levels to human life.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate boat-focused transportation in your world the same way that we eliminate unicycle-focused transportation in ours.  Sure, unicycles exist, but they're a novelty. Whatever you're using a unicycle to do, there's a better, easier way to do it.  There's no real reason to use one as a primary transportation device.

> On an Earth-like planet with clustered continents and large oceans,
> like Pangaea, the easiest method of travel would be boats.

Is it, though?  If your land mass is clustered and your oceans massive, there doesn't seem to be any reason to build ships capable of traversing the ocean.  Where exactly would you be going?  Crossing the ocean in a ship is just a really long, dangerous, difficult way of traveling to the other side of your continent.  Somebody might do it once for the glory, but it will never be seen as a practical mode of transport.

The only remaining use cases for your ocean would be for fishing, or for shuttling people/cargo up and down the coast.  Eliminating the first is easy: you have ample sources of fish available inland, and the only fish in your ocean worth eating are significantly harder to locate and catch.  Building ships and going out to sea to catch fish is such a terrible return-on-investment that it's pointless.

To ensure ships aren't used to move cargo from port to port, ensure your world has much easier ways to get stuff from point A to point B.  Perhaps there's a vast system of navigable lakes and rivers that meet your transportation needs via riverboats and barges while being safer and more predictable than ocean travel.  Add a few canals and you can have a rather extensive system of inland waterways (example, the [Intracoastal Waterway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intracoastal_Waterway) in the US stretches 3000 miles from Boston to the southern tip of Texas).  Having population centers towards the center of the continent and farther from the coast helps your case as well, as the extra work required to haul cargo back and forth to the coast might be greater than what's require to ship it overland.  You can add navigational hazards to the oceans to further reduce the attractiveness of ocean shipping.  Reefs and rocks can make certain areas impassable.  Natural ocean currents and trade winds can be oriented in the wrong direction, or could pull ships out to sea (similar to how it's harder to sail from Europe to South Africa by following the coastline than it is to cross the ocean to Brazil and then cross all the way back).  If ocean transport is significantly more difficult than using inland waterways or transporting things overland, then people aren't going to bother building oceangoing ships.  Your port cities and shipping centers will naturally develop on rivers and trail crossroads instead of coastal areas.

Answer (score 0):

You could design your world around a specific type of weather which would result in frequent or permanent high pressure areas over oceans or specific parts of it. Combined with volcanic activity, this could lead to gases which disperse oxygen accumulating in pockets over vast swathes of ocean. This would make travel in these areas impossible for a civilization with the technology level you mentioned.

Signs of these deadly areas are quite easy to spot (no animals, smell, etc) but the areas themselves are hard to overcome.

However, I am not sure of the hard science behind the feasibility. While the premise, in my opinion, is sound, the gases might disperse into the sea water over time. It would also mean having a sustained level of volcanism below sea level which might have other side effects such as drifting continents.

However, it could also be a story element in which changes to the weather conditions or volcanic activity could easily open up sea routes.

Answer (score 0):

Your world could have had a big asteroid crash into the ocean and cause the shore around the world to be toxic. Or maybe you just have different chemical properties that happen when fresh water mixes with the type of water in your seas which causes a big toxic area bordering all the oceans that is stinky and poisonous.

So there would be organisms, large and small and bacterial processes in that area that stink really, really bad. Humans just stay away because of the stink. They don't even travel within 10 miles of the ocean. Most of them don't even know there are oceans, they just know there are areas that stink so bad. Only people who have bad olfactory glands have ever dared venture near the sea. :) But the air is actually poisonous so those who didn't smell it die before they realize it's too late.

It isn't just the stink, but the air around it is poisonous, like sulfurous or something. You could make it so that the shoreline has organisms that grow with this toxicity or you could make the rocks interact with something in the water that causes this toxicity, but really it's just the shore that's bad, so if humans were able to fly over the shore they'd eventually get past the stinky/poisonous area and maybe reach a normal non-toxic ocean which contributes to normal non-toxic weather patterns, but the wide areas bordering the shoreline are so bad they never go to the ocean.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: The trees of the planet have dense wood to protect them from harsh conditions and insect attacks. However, their density means that while they can definitely be used for construction, making boats out of them is a bad idea. Or the wood is too waterproof for a boat to balance, and would thus make it capsize as soon as it hit the water.

Answer (score 0):

Frequent invariably fatal phenomena - eg

1. Kraken / Sea Monsters - large, unpredictable, undefeatable, ever vigilant, always fatal.
   (These MAY exist on earth currently but, if so, they are very stealthy and rapid in attack and invariable fatal :-). )
2. Frequent rogue waves - again unpredictable and immense and invariably fatal.
   These occur on earth very occasionally and very occasionally sink even large liners.
3. Your choice ...

If the frequency of either of these was somewhat greater than on earth
(much greater for Kraken :-) ) and if they were invariably catastrophic for boats of any sensibly achievable size then boats above that size would not evolve. Boats well above "sensible size" may be built as a trial, but if these always met with disaster the attempts would be 'discouraged'.